# loop over corresponding elements of multiple lists

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization, list-comprehension, mapply

I have a function which takes two inputs. I'd like to pass it two lists of inputs and return a list which applies the function to the corresponding inputs in turn. What is the best practice to do this in Python? I am transitioning from R, where I would use the mapply function.

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    return x + y
res = [myfunc(i, j) for i in [1, 2, 3] for j in [1, 2, 3]] 
# Code above returns all combinations (which I don't need).
# Desired result: [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: You need `zip`: `res = [myfunc(*t) for t in zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3])]`

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that zip() returns a "zip object". The solution involving numpy is also very appreciated, as eventually I may be applying this code to numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
res = [myfunc(x, y) for x, y in zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])]
```

Or for an unknown amount of iterators, do:

```
res = [myfunc(*i) for i in zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

def myfunc(x, y):
    return x + y

sum = np.vectorize(myfunc)(a,b)
print(sum)
#[2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function would be suitable for this, since it allows passing multiple iterables.

```
def my_func(x, y):
    return x + y

xs = (1, 2, 3)
result = list(map(my_func, xs, xs))
```